# Two dimensional Array passing to print after taking values but output doesn't reflect the correct userinput ?? UserInput.printArray()?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
package gameTicTacToe;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameInput extends printGameBoard {

    public static void welcomeMessage(int numberRC) {
        System.out.println("\t Welcome to the Tic Tac Toe game \t");
        System.out.println("\t Please play and enjoy with -->> 0 and 1 <<-- " + numberRC + " X " + numberRC + " \t\n");
    }

    public static void initArray(int array[][], int number) {
            int row = number;
            int column = number;
            System.out.println("\n initializing Array with some values : "); // System.out.println("array length : " + array.length); for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) { constantGameBoard.inputArray[i][j] = 1; } } } public static void main(String[] args) { int input = constantGameBoard.inputForChooseGame(); welcomeMessage(input); initArray(constantGameBoard.inputArray, input); printGameBoard.printArray(constantGameBoard.inputArray, input); UserInput.userInputForGame(input); UserInput.printArray(constantGameBoard.inputArray, input); printGameBoard.printArray(constantGameBoard.inputArray, input); } }
```

Comment: Uh, please refer to the SO question asking guidelines

Comment: don't want to complaint but page was keep asking me to add more details even after adding enough explanation, it's not that friendly to paste question  as easy as it looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constantGameBoard.rowcolumnNumber has been neglected , this is the issue. Now it's resolved

public static void userInputOnBoard(int numberRC, int row , int column ) {



        for(int i = 0 ; i < constantGameBoard.rowcolumnNumber ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("print 1" + "value i " + i);
            for(int j = 0 ; j < constantGameBoard.rowcolumnNumber ; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("print 2" + " value j" + j);
                if( i == row && j == column)
                {
                    System.out.println("print 3");
                    if(numberRC == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("print 4");
                        constantGameBoard.inputArray[i][j]= 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("print 5");
                        constantGameBoard.inputArray[i][j]=0 ;
                    }

                }


            }
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. class

package gameTicTacToe;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class constantGameBoard {

public static  int rowcolumnNumber ;

public static int inputForChooseGame() {

System.out.print("Please type your input row / column : ");
Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
rowcolumnNumber = scr.nextInt() ;


return rowcolumnNumber ;
}
//public static int  inputArray[][] ;

public static int  inputArray[][] = new  int[2][2];


}



2. class

package gameTicTacToe;

public class printGameBoard {

public static void printArray(int array[][], int number) {

int row = number , column = number ;
System.out.println("\n Printing Array with initial values print class : \n");

for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
{

System.out.print(" | ");
  for (int j=0; j < array[i].length ; j++)
  {
 System.out.print(" " + constantGameBoard.inputArray[i][j]  +" | ");
  }
  System.out.println("\n" + "---------------------");
}



}

}

3. class



package gameTicTacToe;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInput {

//static int  inputArray[][] = new  int[3][3];
public static void userInputForGame(int numberRC) {
int row = numberRC; int column = numberRC ;int count = 0 ; 
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
int rowInput ; int columnInput ;



for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++ )
{
for(int j = 0 ; j < column ; j++)
{

if(count == 0)
{
System.out.println("Player 1 : ");
System.out.print("Type your Row : " );
rowInput = scr.nextInt() ;
System.out.print("Type your Column : " );
columnInput = scr.nextInt() ;
count = 1 ;
userInputOnBoard(1,rowInput,columnInput);
System.out.println("\n");
}
else
{
System.out.println("Player 0 : ");
System.out.print("Type your Row : " );
rowInput = scr.nextInt() ;
System.out.print("Type your Column : " );
columnInput = scr.nextInt() ;
count = 0 ;
userInputOnBoard(0,rowInput,columnInput);
System.out.println("\n");

}

}

}
//printArray(inputArray);

}

public static void userInputOnBoard(int numberRC, int row , int column ) {


for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++)
{

for(int j = 0 ; j < column ; j++)
{

if( i == row && j == column)
{
if(numberRC == 1)
{
constantGameBoard.inputArray[i][j]=1;
}
else
{
constantGameBoard.inputArray[i][j]=0;
}

}


}
}


}

public static void userInputValidation(int numberRC, int row , int column ) {


}

public static void printArray(int array[][], int number ) {
int row = number , column = number ;
System.out.println("\n Printing Array with initial values userinput : \n");

for (int i=0; i < array.length ; i++)
{

System.out.print(" | ");
  for (int j=0; j < array[i].length ; j++)
  {
 System.out.print(" " + constantGameBoard.inputArray[i][j] +" | ");
  }
  System.out.println("\n" + "---------------------");
}

}


}

4. class - main 



package gameTicTacToe;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameInput extends printGameBoard{


public static void welcomeMessage(int numberRC) {

System.out.println("\t Welcome to the Tic Tac Toe game \t");
System.out.println("\t Please play and enjoy with -->> 0 and 1 <<--   " + numberRC + "  X  " + numberRC + "  \t\n");
}

public static void initArray(int array[][], int number ) {

int row = number ; int column = number ;
System.out.println("\n initializing Array with some values : ");
//System.out.println("array length : " + array.length);


for (int i=0; i < array.length ; i++)
{
  for (int j=0; j < array[i].length ; j++)
  {
  constantGameBoard.inputArray[i][j] = 99;
  }
}

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

int input = constantGameBoard.inputForChooseGame();
welcomeMessage(input);

initArray(constantGameBoard.inputArray , input);
printGameBoard.printArray(constantGameBoard.inputArray, input );



UserInput.userInputForGame(input);
UserInput.printArray(constantGameBoard.inputArray, input);

}

}
```

Comment: this is the whole code in 4 different classes please ignore small code in question part. Sorry. I can not print final output, you can init with any value like 99. please provide only 2 as a input for now , just to see correct answer